# how to swap elements in a multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, copy-and-swap

I'm working on arrays using php and I am trying to swap items of the array. I have this code:

```
<html>
<body>
<p>
<?php
    $test2 = array  (   array("!","#","#"),
                        array("@","!","#"),
                        array("@","@","!",)  
                    );

    for($f=0; $f < count($test2); $f++)
    {
        for($g=0; $g < count($test2); $g++)
        {
            if($g >= 2)
            {
            echo "{$test2[$f][$g] } ";          
            }
            else
            {
            echo "{$test2[$f][$g] }- ";         
            }           
        }   
        echo "<br>";
    }

    ...
```

the code above has an output of:

```
!- #- #
@- !- #
@- @- !
```

I am trying to swap the index of the arrays so the output will be like this:

```
!- @- @
#- !- @
#- #- !
```

Thank you guys for the help.

Comment: So you are trying to reverse the order of both the inner and outer arrays or do you want to leave the arrays intact and simply output them in reverse order?

Comment: Why you don't decrement in your for loops? http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/kb5-m3x

Comment: You could also simplify the `if`. Replace it with: `echo ($g >= 2) ? "{$test2[$f][$g] } " : "{$test2[$f][$g] }- ";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just switch the column to row,

```
$test2[$f][$g] => $test2[$g][$f]
```

**[DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/IgqAez)**.